# Why can I not access this Rust simple server from the Internet?

Tags: web-services, rust

I have the following server:

```
extern crate simple_server;
use crate::simple_server::*;

fn main() {
    let host = "127.0.0.1";
    let port = "7878";

    let server = Server::new(|request, mut response| {
        println!("Request received. {} {}", request.method(), request.uri());
        println!("=============BODY=================");
        let mut v: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        for b in request.body().iter() {
            v.push(*b);
        }
        let body_as_str = String::from_utf8(v);

        match body_as_str {
            Ok(strr) => println!("{}", strr),
            Err(e) => println!("{}", e),
        }

        //ROUTING
        match (request.method(), request.uri().path()) {
            (&Method::GET, "/") => {
                Ok(response.body("<h1>Hi!</h1><p>Hello hacker!</p>".as_bytes().to_vec())?)
            }
            (&Method::POST, "/") => {
                Ok(response.body("<h1>Hi!</h1><p>Hello hacker!</p>".as_bytes().to_vec())?)
            }
            (_, _) => {
                response.status(StatusCode::NOT_FOUND);
                Ok(response.body("<h1>404</h1><p>Not found!<p>".as_bytes().to_vec())?)
            }
        }
    });
    println!("Listening on: {} port {}", host, port);
    server.listen(host, port);
}
```

I'm not able to access the page going to http://my_server_ip:7878/ from the Internet.

I have my server's firewall setup to allow all on `7878` and also, other simple servers work just fine when configured to listen on that port, which makes me think this is a code problem with my specific Rust application. An example of a server which works fine is static-server on npm.

However, when I test this application on my build machine by going to `"127.0.0.1:7878"`, it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `"127.0.0.1"` for the `host` variable you denied any connection that doesn't come from this address. Use `"0.0.0.0"`, the unspecified address, for example.