# Why is are my published ports not working?

Tags: docker, curl, networking, rust, rust-rocket

I've created a docker image containing a rust application that responds to get requests on port 8000.  The application itself is a basic example using  the rocket library (https://rocket.rs/) it looks like this

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]

#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

#[get("/")]
fn index() -> &'static str {
    "Hello, world!"
}

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![index]).launch();
}
```

I have compiled this and called it `server`

I then created a Docker file to host it

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y curl

COPY server /root/

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["/root/server"]
```

I build the docker image with 
`$ docker build -t port_test` and run it with `$ docker run -p 8000:8000 port_test`

At this point it all looks good

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED                     STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
3befe0c272f7        port_test           "/root/server"      7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   festive_wilson
```

If I run curl within the container it works fine

```
$ docker exec -it 3befe0c272f7 curl -s localhost:8000
Hello, world!
```

However I can't do the same from the host

```
$ curl localhost:8000
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: That sounds like the symptom of the server process binding to 127.0.0.1 and being unreachable from outside the container, with the answer being to bind to 0.0.0.0, but I can't tell you how to address it for this particular server stack.

Comment: I bet you are right. I'll try setting it to 0.0.0.0

Comment: That was the issue.  If you make this an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 9):

David Maze was correct.  The problem was that the process was binding to localhost in the container.  I added a Rocket.toml file with the following entries

```
[global]
address = "0.0.0.0"

[development]
address = "0.0.0.0"
```

and now it works fine.

Thanks David.

Comment: the profile `development` is deprecated. Use `debug` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Rocket have different standard configuration, please try `staging` or `prod` to be able to do what you want, [source](https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/configuration/).

```
ROCKET_ENV=staging cargo run
```

See also:

- [Why can I not access this Rust simple server from the Internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53900614/why-can-i-not-access-this-rust-simple-server-from-the-internet/53900809#53900809)