# How to open rust-rocket server to LAN?

Tags: rust, network-programming, rust-rocket

I tried rocket, cargo run, access to http://localhost:8000 and looks well.
However, I failed to access to http://192.168.developing.pc:8000 from other PC in LAN.
I tried http://192.168.developing.pc:8000 in developing PC but was not able to access.

At first I thought it is related to firewall but I was confused because it was not able to access from own machine.

How can I do?

I'm completely not familiar with networking so that I'm not sure if only the executable I built is enough or need other service such as nginx or IIS or something.

I'm developing in windows 10 and want to deploy on ubuntu finally. (ubuntu machine is not ready)

Thank you.

Comment: you need to config rocket to listen to "0.0.0.0" or launch as staging mode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119006/why-is-are-my-published-ports-not-working/54120236#54120236

Comment: solved. I thought the duplicated was related to docker but not so that. thank you.

Comment: you said *I* have to consider? well, 1) I want to upvote as answer. I'm grad if you rewite as Answer. 2) I don't know how to close myself. any backdoor for asker?

Answer (score 1):

export ROCKET_ENV=stage ;cargo run

Comment: This should be `ROCKET_ENV=staging cargo run`